# Illustrator: how to add perspective to text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, illustrator-effects

I am trying to achieve this effect in Illustrator.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the 'Effect → Distort & Transform → Free Distort' tool and more info [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/scaling-shearing-distorting-objects.html).

Comment: Perfect! that's the tool I was looking for

Answer (score 3):

Another possiblity is to use 3D effect Extrude & Bevel. It offers easy manipulation of the apparent watching direction. Here the extrusion thickness is zero and the light effects (=shading) are turned OFF.

[image]

The adjustment dialog can be reopened in the appearance panel. Click the effect icon there. Expanding the appearance fixes the effect to uneditable.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The first solution doesn't provide accurate distortion since the thickness of the text stays the same in the distance. The 3D tool does it perfectly. Thank you for this.

Comment: There is also a 3D move in the effects that is the same thing as bevel minus the extrude. Its slightly less messy in output

Answer (score 0):

A combination of the effects of 3D and sheer may be the complete solution when distorting type since the vertical stems of the characters need to remain perpendicular to the perspective baseline.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! could you add some screen shots to your answer to illustrate how your solution would work?